# Is it possible to create directories under Android/data/data/your_package/ files

Tags: android, directory

I would like to save some files in different directories under Android/data/data/my_app_package/files directory. I am able to obtain the path to the "files" directory by calling context.getExternalFilesDir(null), but can't create a directory under the path returned. Does anyone know why?

Thanks,

Comment: In order to write to the directory you need the permission, have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I did, but failed to create a directory.

Comment: Could you post code of how you're creating your directory?

Comment: How are you creating the directory?

Comment: File root = SoundApplication.getAppContext().getExternalFilesDir(null);
File soundDir = new File(root, "/sound-dir");
if (!soundDir.exists()) {
    boolean dir = soundDir.mkdirs();
    System.out.println("dir = " + dir);
}  soundDir.mkdirs() returned true, but I don't see "sound-dir" in Android.data.mayPackage.files directory.

Comment: Post code in your post. Not in comments. Write a decent post.

Comment: The path you mentioned does not exist. See the real path with getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Tell which tool you use to check if diectories exist. But start mentioning the real path.

Answer (score 0):

```
File root = SoundApplication.getAppContext().getExternalFilesDir(null); 
File soundDir = new File(root, "/sound-dir"); 
if (!soundDir.exists()) { 
    boolean dir = soundDir.mkdirs(); 
    System.out.println("dir = " + dir); 
}
```

soundDir.mkdirs() returned true, but I don't see "sound-dir" in Android.data.mayPackage.files directory with Windows explorer.